# How to remove an animation in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I would like to remove an animation and just print the `result` but I don't know how to remove the animation from this `result`
Here is where the `result` is:

```
onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
       builder: (context) => NextPage(
           result: (something + other_thing)
```

And this is how I am printing it:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ValueListenableBuilder<String>(
              valueListenable: _animation,
              builder: (context, value, child) {
                return Text(
                  'The result is $value',   //It has to print the result here, but without any animations
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I was wondering if I need to remove this ValueListenableBuilder, but I don't know how to access the `result` from the code above.

Comment: *"I was wondering if I need to remove this ValueListenableBuilder, but I don't know how to access the result from the code above."* - `'The result is ${_animation.value}'`

Comment: Shouldn't it remove the _animation? I just need the `result` value appearing on the next page

Comment: I would like to remove the code that makes animations, I just don't know how to print the result after doing it.

Comment: *"I would like to remove the code that makes animations"* - so try to remove `ValueListenableBuilder`

Comment: Yeah, I was doing it. But the thing is that I don't know how to print the result inside `children: [ ] `. I mean, what do I type to do that?

Comment: `Text('The result is ${_animation.value}')`

Comment: Isn't it considering the animation? I would like to remove all the animations

Comment: no, it is not, now `Text` is built only once

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236949/discussion-between-bilbo-bo-and-pskink).

Comment: @pskink I've just invited you to a chat room

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to use ValueListenableBuilder, you can use `Navigator.push` to help you move data between different screens without animations. If you dont know how Navigator works, here is a simple video that explains how it works. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NT3XakU4Dcw

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: I'll take a look at it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

under the hood, navigator execute animation for each action. so just set duration to 0 to remove animation

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
  context, 
  PageRouteBuilder(
    pageBuilder: (_, _, _) => MyPage(),
    transitionDuration: const Duration(seconds: 0), // here disabling animation
));
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?